# All records are null laravel

Tags: php, laravel, sqlite, sql-null

I'm having a problem when I save an object in SQLite database. In the form I insert not null value, the request has the right data, but when I save the object in the database there is only null value. In the form I provided only 1 example but the form is repeated for the various inputs.

**CustomerController.php**

```php
$data = request()->validate([
    'nome' => 'required|max:40|unique:users',
    'cognome' => 'required|max:40|unique:users',
    'cap' => 'required|min:5',
    'comune' => 'required|max:40',
    'via' => 'required|max:40',
    'civico' => 'required|max:40',
    'telefono' => 'required',
    'email' => 'email|unique:users',
]);
$customer = new Customer();
$customer->nome = $request->input('nome');
$customer->cognome = $request->input('cognome');
$customer->cap = $request->input('cap');
$customer->comune = $request->input('comune');
$customer->via = $request->input('via');
$customer->civico = $request->input('civico');
$customer->telefono = $request->input('telefono');
$customer->email = $request->input('email');

($customer->save());

return view('home');
```

**web.php**

```php
Route::get('customer/create', 'CustomerController@create')->middleware(CheckAdmin::class)->name('customer.create');

Route::post('customer/', 'CustomerController@store')->middleware(CheckAdmin::class)->name('customer.store');
```

**form**

```html
<form method="POST" action="/customer/">
    @csrf
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="nome" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Nome') }}</label>

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input id="nome" type="text" class="form-control @error('nome') is-invalid @enderror" name="nome" value="{{ old('nome') }}" required autocomplete="nome" autofocus>

            @error('nome')
                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                </span>
            @enderror
        </div>
    </div>
    ...
</form>
```

**model**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Customer extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['*'];


    protected $table = 'customers';

    public $nome;
    public $cognome;
    public $cap;
    public $comune;
    public $via;
    public $civico;
    public $telefono;
    public $email;

}
```

Comment: Just out of interest, WHY the brackets around `($customer->save());` they are so not necessary

Comment: please try dd(($customer) after ($customer->save());

Comment: Function should look like: public function store(Request $request) {....}. Validation should look like: $data = $request->validate(.....) ;

Comment: Be sure that you added all `fillable` field in your model, and change `($customer->save());` to `$customer->save();`

Comment: if i do a dd i get the right data

Comment: please share your Customer model

Comment: I have $fillable with all variable and the table name set with the SQLite table name. Then I have all variable (ex. nome, cognome ecc) with getters and setters

Comment: I'm not sure about it but in your code `$customer = new Customer();` does it need `()` and also in `($customer->save());`

Comment: I rewrite that line like this $customer->save()

Comment: try to change this line `$customer = new Customer();` to `$customer = new Customer;` but I'm not sure if this is the problem or not..

Comment: I done that but nothing changes

Comment: ok then, are you sure your validation is passed? try `dd($request->all());` after validation?

Comment: yes the validation is pass with the correct data, but when I save it all values are null

Comment: ok then the problem is in your model, please share your model (full) so that we can check

Comment: ('<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Customer extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['*'];


    protected $table = 'customers';

    public $nome;
    public $cognome;
    public $cap;
    public $comune;
    public $via;
    public $civico;
    public $telefono;
    public $email;
    
}')

Comment: sorry for the layout but i can't post it like code

Comment: you can edit your question, and add your model..anyway we can check from her also

Comment: I edit the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to change your model

```
class Customer extends Model
{
  protected $fillable = [
    'nome', 'cognome', 'cap', 'comune', 'via', 'civico', 'telefono', 'email',
  ];

  protected $table = 'customers';
}
```